# Openquery error 'Incorrect Syntax near keyword Transaction'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, openquery

I have a stored procedure that uses openquery to fetch data from a table in a linked server.
I need to pass a parameter in the query, so it as below

```
   Declare @query nvarchar(max)
   Declare @empRequestid nvarchar(max)
   
   Set @empRequestid = '100001' --(This is an input parameter)
   
   Set @query = 'SELECT * INTO [dbo].tblEmp_Report FROM OPENQUERY (SALESIT_SC3VIS_DEV, 
   ''SELECT EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber
   FROM   XXEmployee_Temp_ReportTable        
   WHERE  1=1        AND  description =''Transaction Employee Report''      
   and emp_requestid ='+@empRequestid +'        
   ORDER  BY period_id'')'

   EXEC(@query)
```

The error is get however is,
**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be `description =''''Transaction Employee Report''''`. You have a literal string, inside a literal string, so you need to double escape the single quotes (`'`).

Comment: FYI the simplest method of debugging a dynamic statement is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` it. If you did that, you'd spot the error pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Declare @query nvarchar(max)
   Declare @empRequestid nvarchar(max)
   
   Set @empRequestid = '100001' --(This is an input parameter)
   
   Set @query = 'SELECT * INTO [dbo].tblEmp_Report FROM OPENQUERY (SALESIT_SC3VIS_DEV, 
   ''SELECT EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber
   FROM   XXEmployee_Temp_ReportTable        
   WHERE  1=1        AND  description =''''Transaction Employee Report''''
   and emp_requestid ='+@empRequestid +'        
   ORDER  BY period_id'')'


   SELECT @query
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the Problem using Print query

```
Declare @query nvarchar(max)
Declare @empRequestid nvarchar(max)

Set @empRequestid = '100001' --(This is an input parameter)

Set @query = 'SELECT * INTO [dbo].tblEmp_Report FROM OPENQUERY (SALESIT_SC3VIS_DEV, 
''SELECT EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber
FROM   XXEmployee_Temp_ReportTable        
WHERE  1=1        AND  description =''Transaction Employee Report''      
and emp_requestid ='+@empRequestid +'        
ORDER  BY period_id'')'

Print(@query)
```

Now run the query and find the issue then change the "Print" to "Exec"